# Como cargar un FormData a un servicio Angular? Por que al momento de mandar el servicio me llega vacio a donde lo mando

Tags: angular, typescript

Buen dia.

Lo que pasa es que estoy tratando de cargar un FormData a un servicio Front que luego en Back me esta llegando todo vacio y pues ya probe con Postman enviar un formdata y en back llega todos los datos como los mando entonces deduje que el error esta en el Front que podria ser mi error???

este es mi formulario
reporte.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="soporteForm" role="form">
                <div fxLayout="row wrap" style="height: 100px">
                    <!--primer titulo-->
                    <div fxFlexOrder="1" fxLayout="column" fxFlex.xs="70" fxFlex.gt-xs="70" fxFlex.gt-sm="20" fxLayoutAlign="space-around stretch">
                        <h3 fxFill color="warn" fxFlex.xs="70" fxFlex.gt-xs="70" fxFlex.gt-sm="70" fxFlex="100">Pregunta o Asunto del Tiket:</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!--primer input-->
                    <div fxFlexOrder="1" fxLayout="column" fxFlex.xs="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="70" fxFlex.gt-sm="50" fxLayoutAlign="space-around stretch">
                        <mat-form-field fxFill color="warn" fxFlex.xs="70" fxFlex.gt-xs="70" fxFlex.gt-sm="70" fxFlex="100" appearance="outline">
                            <mat-label>Pregunta o Asunto del Tiket</mat-label>
                            <input matInput id="preuntaTiket" formControlName="pregunta" type="text" [value]="" placeholder="Pregunta o Asunto del Tiket" [type]="">
                            <mat-error>Este campo es obligatorio</mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>



                </div>

                <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------- -->
                <div >

                    <!--segundo titulo-->
                    <div>
                        <h3>Detalles de la petición: </h3>
                    </div>

                    <!--segundo input-->
                    <div>
                        <input type="file" (change)="getfile($event)" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->

                <div>

                    <div>
                        <button (click)="enviarTicket()">
                        Enviar Ticket
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Este es mi ts aca llega todo correcto segun por los console log

reporte.component.ts

```
    soporteForm:FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.soporteForm = this.fb.group({
      pregunta: ['', [
        Validators.required
      ]]
    });
  }

  enviarTicket(){
    if(this.soporteForm.valid){          
      let datas = new FormData()
      datas.append('pregunta', this.soporteForm.value.pregunta)
      datas.append('evidencia', this.evidenciaFoto.get('evidencia'))
      
      console.log(datas);
      this.soporteService.createTikeckt(datas).subscribe();
    }
}

evidenciaFoto = new FormData()
  getfile(fileupload:Event){
    this.evidenciaFoto.append('evidencia', fileupload.target['files'][0])

    console.log(this.evidenciaFoto.get('evidencia'));
 }
```

Pues segun vi con console log que estan ahi me di cuenta que llega todo bien osea no entienfdo que pasa que llega al back vacio
reporte.service.ts

```
createTikeckt(data:FormData){
console.log(data.get('pregunta'));
console.log(data.get('evidencia'));;//en esto si me doy cuenta que la 
//info llega bien talvez este equivocado y en realidad esta llegando hasta aca vacio

let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/soporte/crear/ticket/`, data);
```

}

Por favor ayuda

Comment: Quita esta línea: `headers = headers.set( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")`

Comment: @Lobos ya la comente pero sigue sin llegar nada al back :c

Comment: Es obvio pero hay que preguntar, los campos del backend coinciden con lo que estas mandando desde el front?

Comment: @Legna Pues es que y estoy manejando Paython y pues no esta llegando ni siquiera nada en el request esta llegando vacio pero con Postman envie un formdata y si me lo esta recibiendo muy bien con los campos y todo

Comment: @Lobos mira esto me reponde el back cuando hago el envio osea clic `JSON parse error - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 336: invalid start byte`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es cierto lo que comentan, revisa sobre todo las mayúsculas es muy común que pase,

también puedes probar el botón ponle:

type="submit"

y como último comentario que te podría hacer es mandar el .value
`<button type="submit" (click)="enviarTicket(soporteForm.value)"> Enviar Ticket </button>`

Comment: @Legna Pues es que y estoy manejando Paython y pues no esta llegando ni siquiera nada en el request esta llegando vacio pero con Postman envie un formdata y si me lo esta recibiendo muy bien con los campos y todo